# Where do you pass get query params to to test aiohttp endpoints

Tags: unit-testing, aiohttp

I am testing aiohttp endpoints that I created. On following some approaches given in the doc, below code works fine. However, here where do we pass {name} arg that endpoint has to test?

So if suppose my url is `localhost/hello/Alice` and it prints Hello Alice. Now in the test case where do I pass `Alice` as the name here? Also, what if I allow just `Alice` and `Bob` as valid names and rest names are not supported by my logic. So in this case, I need to specify certain names to see what values are valid and invalid.

How can I pass certain values in first place is my question because all I am doing is just a place holder and not passing any actual name in the below test case.

```
subapp_routes = web.RouteTableDef()

@subapp_routes.get('/{name}')
async def hello_name(request):
    name = request.match_info.get('name')
    txt = "Hello {}\n".format(name)
    return web.Response(text=txt)

@pytest.fixture
def cli(loop, test_client):
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get('/', hello)
    app.router.add_get('/{name}', hello_name)
    return loop.run_until_complete(test_client(app))


async def test_hello(cli):
    resp = await cli.get('/{name}')
    assert resp.status == 200
    text = await resp.text()
    assert 'Hello {name}' in text
```

Comment: Please look on aiohttp own test suite: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/tree/master/tests It has plenty of tests. Files ending with "`_functional`" are most useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply there are two options:

1. generate the url yourself eg. just use `resp = await cli.get('/Alice')`
2. use the app's `url_for` method to generate urls:

```py
    ...
    app.router.add_get('/{name}', hello_name, name='hello-name')
    ...

async def test_hello(cli):
    url = cli.server.app.router['hello-name'].url_for(name='Alice')
    resp = await cli.get(url)
    assert resp.status == 200
    text = await resp.text()
    assert 'Hello {name}' in text
```

Lots of examples [here](https://github.com/tutorcruncher/socket-server/blob/master/tests/test_public_views.py)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @AndrewSvetlov and @SColvin. I referred through both of your links and from Andrew's implementation I got this as well:

```
@pytest.fixture
def cli(loop, test_client):
    app = web.Application()
    app.router.add_get(r'/{name}', hello_name)
    return loop.run_until_complete(test_client(app))


valid_names = ['Alice', 'Bob']

@pytest.mark.parametrize('name', valid_names)
async def test_hello(name, cli):
    resp = await cli.get('/{}'.format(name))
    assert resp.status == 200
    text = await resp.text()
    print(text)
    assert 'Hello {}'.format(name) in text
```